# Add interface library as SYSTEM in modern CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, interface, header-only

I'm currently transforming my C++ project from simply using a Makefile to using CMake. As I'm unfamiliar with CMake, I try and avoid learning "old" CMake and stick to "modern CMake" best practices, e.g. described [here](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1#forget-the-commands-add_compile_options-include_directories-link_directories-link_libraries).

However, I could not figure out how to include a simple, header-only, third party library *without getting bothered with warnings about that library*.

Say I have a project structure like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/
  CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
third-party-lib/
  foo/
    foo.h
```

Say `main.cpp` uses `foo`: `#include <foo.h>`

The problem is, I use a bunch of warning flags and `foo.h` introduces some warnings that I don't care about, as I'm not the author and it's nothing serious.

In a classic Makefile I would just have written `-isystem third-party-lib/foo` somewhere appropriate and be done.

In CMake, I achieved this by a `include_directories(SYSTEM PRIVATE third-party-lib/foo)` in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`.

Now, according to the link above, I should keep my hands off `include_directories()` to avoid hidden dependencies and I think that this is a good idea. I'd rather specify for each target that actually needs `foo` to include that library and treat it as 'don't warn me here'. As I understand it, the approach would be:

- find `foo` target in top-level `CMakeLists.txt`
- `target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE foo)` or so in `src/CMakeLists.txt`

How would I achieve that, i.e. what is the command for finding, and where to specify the `SYSTEM` property? Or any other suggestions for how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a header-only library in modern CMake, you can use [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) with `SYSTEM INTERFACE`. You can place this in your top-level CMake file, before processing the `src/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(foo SYSTEM INTERFACE 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party-lib/foo
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is `target_include_directories`.  It works like `include_directories` but on a per-target basis.

```
add_executable(foo foo.c)
target_include_directories(foo SYSTEM
    PRIVATE sys_inc
)
```